# Visual Studio Source Control Explorer - propagate "Latest" status

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, source-control-explorer

I am currently using VS 2015 connecting to a TFS.

When some file changes on the server (e.g. through a colleague's check-in) the "Latest" column of that file changes to "No" in my Source Control Explorer.

However, this status change is not propagated up through the directory hierarchy, which means I would have to check all leaf directories for possible changes.

Can "Source Control Explorer" or TFS settings be changed to propagate the status?

Comment: No that's not possible. But since Get Latest Version only retrieves changed files, you can safely execute it regularly at the top directory level.

Comment: You can always write VSPackage that will generate that list for you.

Comment: @jessehouwing: Thanks for your reply, but that's exactly what I don't want. 

I would like to get a list of changes on the server side without updating my local repository (like, for example, any SVN client can show you items an update *would* change)

Comment: You can do that from the commandline easy enough: `tf get /recursive /noprompt /preview`. From the UI this preview option is not available.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have noticed the status of your working file have changed, you may need to do a 'get latest' manually.

If you didn't notice, it's also no big deal. There will be conflicts pop up during  your check in. You just need to solve the conflicts , merge your local version with the latest version of TFS to generate a new latest version after checked in. TFS will **only force the server side file 'latest', not the local side.**

Moreover, just like jessehouwing said. you can through [tf command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) `tf get /recursive /noprompt /preview` to list the changes between your local and server side.